# PostgreSQL : Display the id which do not have a specific attribute value

Tags: postgresql

Structure

| ID | Attribute_id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id_1 | attribute_1 | name_1 |
| id_1 | attribute_1 | name_2 |
| id_1 | attribute_1 | name_3 |
| id_1 | attribute_2 | xxx |
| id_1 | attribute_3 | yyy |
| id_2 | attribute_2 | aaa |
| id_2 | attribute_3 | bbb |
| id_3 | attribute_1 | name_1 |
| id_3 | attribute_2 | xxx |

**Result expected**

| ID |
| --- |
| id_2 |

Need to display ids not having name (not associated with attribute_1)
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `EXCEPT` operator:

```
select id from your_table 
except
select id from your_table where attribute_id = 'attribute_1';
```

Comment: How to modify this if I have joins ? OR have to find within a set of ids?  @Littlefoot

Comment: That's a new problem; I suggest you open a new question, posting test case which shows what kind of joins and/or set of IDs you're talking about.